# JSON string with variables out of Python

Tags: python, html, json, variables, stringify

I'm making a webpage where variables(sensor value) out of python are displayed on the webpage.

But it won't let me use variables in the `JSON.stringify()`.
The goal is that from python a sensor value is read, and this must be sent to the html webpage
How can I program this?
All the sensors has their own ID

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
import json

data_zone = json.dumps({ "id": 1})

html_body = f'''<td><b><section id={data_zone}></section></b></td>'''
```

Comment: Can u explain that a bit more? for example for sensor1 and sensor2. in the code above

Comment: you can do this
```
import json

data_zone = json.dumps({ "id": 1})

html_body = f'''<td><b><section id={data_zone}></section></b></td>'''

```